# Dismiss Multiple popovers xcode

Tags: xcode, ipad

I have a page with multiple popovers that I am trying to dismiss when another popover appears I am using the following code but it doesn't seem to dismiss the popover

```
-(IBAction)OISButton:(id)sender{
    if(![popoverController isPopoverVisible]){
        OISView *oisView = [[OISView alloc] init];
        UIPopoverController *pop = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:oisView];
        [pop setDelegate:self];
        [pop presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
        [pop setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 460)];
        [oisView release];

    }
    else{
        // close popover
        [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }


}
```

Any suggestions on how to modify this code? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Tom for putting me in the right direction, I have included the code below for one popover with a view called OISView in a format to handle multiple popovers:

```
-(IBAction)OISButton:(id)sender{
    if([popoverController isPopoverVisible]){
        [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];


} else
{
    OISView *oisView = [[OISView alloc] init];
    UIPopoverController *pop = [[UIPopoverController alloc]   initWithContentViewController:oisView];
    self.popoverController = pop; 
    [pop setDelegate:self];
    [pop presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    [pop setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 460)];
    [oisView release];


}
}
```

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt No, this is **not** against Stack Overflow rules. The OP is free to accept whichever answer they think helped them the most or not accept an answer at all. PS: a more constructive comment would explain *why* the code leaks.

Answer (score 2):

You're not assigning to `popoverController`, which might explain the problems you're having.

Comment: Can you please explain more I am a novice at all this

Comment: You are calling `[popoverController isPopoverVisible]` but you're never telling the object what this `popoverController` is. You'll want to `this.popoverController = pop;`

Comment: Do you mean OISview.popoverController=pop; in this case?